# numpy.vectorize function signature

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I have 2 arrays:

```py
>>> a.shape
(9, 3, 11)
>>> b.shape
(9,)
```

I would like to compute the equivalent of `c[i, j] = f(a[i, j, :], b[i])` where `f(a0, b0)` is a function that takes 2 parameters, with `len(a0) == 11` and `len(b0) == 9`. Here, `i` is iterating on `range(9)` and `j` is iterating on `range(3)`.

Is there a way to code this using `numpy.vectorize`? Or is it simpler with some clever broadcasting?

I have been trying for 2 hours and I just don't understand how to make it work... I tried to broadcast or to use signatures but to no avail.

Comment: `np.array([f(a[i,j,:], b[i]) for j in range(3)] for i in range(9)])`.  `a + b[:,None,None]` will work but the result is (9,3,11).  Or maybe `np.sum(a + b[:,None,None]).axis=2)` if you want (9,3), but then you might as well `np.sum(a, axis=2)` first.

Comment: `np.vectorize` in default mode passes scalar values to the function.  There is a `signature` option that makes it pass arrays, but it is trickier to use, and even slower.  `apply_along_axis` can iterate on your `i,j` dimensions of `a` (slowly), but it can't, at the same time iterate on `b`.  It's just a one array iterator.  The nested list comprehension is probably your best option.

Comment: A sample of the function might help.  Also you need to make it clear what the function returns.  Is it as scalar, so `c` can be a numeric dtype array.  That requires, I assume, some sort of reduction on the size 11 dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj, in the end I could find a solution: `np.vectorize(f, signature="(k),(1)->()")` and then I have to call it like `f(a, b[:, None, None]`. Do you think this would be much slower than a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I could make it work like this:

```py
>>> f = np.vectorize(f, signature="(k),(1)->()")
>>> print(a.shape)
(9, 3, 11)
>>> print(b.shape)
(9,)
>>> print(f(a, b[:, None, None]).shape)
(9, 3)
```

This ensures that `f` gets called with the correct shapes and iterates properly. It is frankly not straightforward from the Numpy documentation to understand the trick to use a `(1)` in the signature for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.apply_along_axis` is what you need.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones( (9,3,11) )
b = np.ones( 9 )

def f(a0, b0):
    return sum(a0[:9]+b0)

c = np.apply_along_axis( f, 2, a, b )
print(c)
```

`c`'s shape is (9,3).

Comment: I get a (9, 3, 9) shaped `c`.

Comment: OK, `f` needs to return one value. not a list of 9.  Now `c` is (9,3).

Comment: You could do just `return np.sum(a0) + b0`, so we don't need the index in the function definition! The important thing is to return the scalar value.

Comment: That won't work, because `b0` is an array of 9.  It will do a scalar addition and return a list, which is how I ended up with (9,3,9) in the first place.  HOWEVER, I only made up that dummy function because you didn't provide yours.  I presume yours is a bit more complicated.